# I get to do scroll

Tags: ionic-framework, chart.js

I make the application ionic 3 and use the library [chortjs](https://www.chartjs.org/)for sharing graphs. Since the width of the mimic screen is not large and I do not want to fit in all the 12 months I want to scroll. I do this:

```
  <ion-scroll padding scrollX="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"> 
    <canvas id="myChartDiogram" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  </ion-scroll>
```

But the scroll does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way

```
<ion-scroll padding scrollX="true" style="width:100vh;height:100vh;overflow-x: scroll" > 
    <canvas id="myChartDiogram" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
  </ion-scroll>
```